# I want to modal tableView Cell data backward to the main View

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I want to modalViewController's table cell data pass to the main View.

Using Protocol delegate. but

```
 Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

This error occur where i remark at the ModalViewController.

Using Protocol method is wrong?.
I use this protocol code another mini project textField's text data pass back and forward. In there it works well.
So i use it in cell data pass

What am i Miss ? Please help.

Bottom Link is my Simulator.

[ModalTableViewDataPass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpzwh.jpg)
   
**MainViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var show: UITextField!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        show.placeholder = "HAHA"
        show.delegate = self
        show.inputView = UIView()
        show.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        if textField == show {
            moveToFindAdrVC()
            print("주소 검색해라잉")
        }
        
    }
    
    func moveToFindAdrVC() {
        let modalVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ModalViewController") as? ModalViewController
        self.present(modalVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
extension ViewController: PassDataToVc {
    func passData(str: String){
        show.text = str
    }
}
```

**ModalTableView**

```
import UIKit

class ModalViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    

    var data = ["as","df","qw","er"]
    
    var delegate: PassDataToVc!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let passData = data[indexPath.row]
        
        let sb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
        
        //sb?.show.text = passData
        
        delegate.passData(str: passData)//Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
protocol PassDataToVc {
    func passData(str: String)
}
```

Comment: You haven't assigned `self` to the delegate property in `prepare(for:)`. You should use a normal optional, not an implicitly unwrapped optional to avoid a crash in the case where the delegate is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delegate` in `ModalViewController` is never set, hence it's `nil`.

But there is a more convenient solution, protocol/delegate is not needed at all.

Delete the code related to protocol/delegate

```
extension ViewController: PassDataToVc {
    func passData(str: String){
        show.text = str
    }
}

var delegate: PassDataToVc!
```

---

and replace

```
delegate.passData(str: passData)
```

with

```
(presentingViewController as? ViewController)?.show.text = passData
```